# mPDF avoid table shrink

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mPDF (version 6). I have an issue with table shrink. I dont want my table to shrink, I want all my tables to be of same size. In below example, you can see two tables, I want them to be same size.

Here is the PHP code used

```
$html  = file_get_contents('test.html');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("../mpdf.php");
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
ob_clean();


$mpdf=new mPDF("c","A3","","",32,25,27,25,16,13); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode("fullpage");
$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit=1;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output("mpdf.pdf","I");
exit;
```

Here is the HTML

HTML is so big (test.html). So this is link for [HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/gwz67aq8/1/)

I want them to be look similar(i.e same size without shrink). In above code I can see table sizes are different sizes, I want them to be of same size . Here is the generated PDF [link](https://www.scribd.com/document/386088347/mpdfSO)

You can see that first table got shrunk, while second table size is different. It is also acceptable, that after 1st paragraph, the table is onto next page, Main concept is to avoid shrink

I have also tried with `$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;` and `<table autosize="1">`, but still its showing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Same nature of problem i was facing. I have added following styles and it worked for me.

```
 <table style='overflow: wrap;min-width: 33%'>
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean table will not shrink, even we have many rows and data